# Under Windows 10 _chdrive changes directory as well?

Tags: winapi, directory

I don't recall prior windows having issues with `_chdrive()` but was using VS2008.  Using version from VS2017, it calls `SetCurrentDirectoryW()` with a drive letter.  `e.g. SetCurrentDirectoryW(L"D:")`.  If I emulate the non-windows `chdir()` from DOS where it only changes the path and not the drive using the code below where the CWD is `D:\xyz\abc` and send a request to change the path to `C:\whatever`:

```
  int curdrv=_getdrive();
  if (_tchdir(path)!=0) {
    // err
  }
  _chdrive(curdrv);
```

if I then call `_tgetdcwd(0)` the current directory returned is `D:\` and not `D:\xyz\abc`.

I can code around this which will be a hassle, did something break or has `_chdrive()` always been broken?

TIA!!

Comment: I think the problem is VS2017 - _chdrive changes to `D:`, internally SetCurrentDirectory says it appends a backslash, therefore the correct value it should have used in _chdrive is `D:.` which would yield `D:.\\` ??  I'll have to try it.

Comment: No, `D:.` doesn't help, still sets it to root.

Comment: If I get the current directory, set the current directory to the same, then try the above, it works (still using `.` at the moment)

Comment: [`_chdrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdrive?view=vs-2019) does change drive not directory. It has no idea of directory information.

Comment: I doesn't work if you haven't set a directory on the drive first.  It default to root (the clib should handle that on startup, but doesn't).

Comment: I want to confirm with you that if you launch(debug) the application from Visual Studio? If it is true, this issue due to the working directory is Visual Studio configuration and environment specified.(Not working directory belongs to your application since you never set it.) You can try to launch the application from CMD it will not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

after change to different drive (Here is C drive.), then return back to initial drive using `_chdrive`, the **current working directory is changed**. (Here it changes from `D:\Win32-Cases\ChangeDir\ChangeDir` to `D:\Win32-Cases\ChangeDir`) The following snapshot can show this issue.

[image]

Because you just change the drive using `_chdrive` (`D:`) instead of directory. So the last directory returned (`D:\Win32-Cases\ChangeDir`) from `_tgetcwd` is system remembered, it is not what `_chdrive` does for you.

> Although each process can have only one current directory, if the
>   application switches volumes by using the SetCurrentDirectory
>   function, the **system remembers the last current path for each volume
>   (drive letter)**. This behavior will manifest itself only when
>   specifying a drive letter without a fully qualified path when changing
>   the current directory point of reference to a different volume. This
>   applies to either Get or Set operations.

Refer to "[Changing the Current Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/changing-the-current-directory)".

If this is true, but why it remembers path `D:\Win32-Cases\ChangeDir` instead of `D:\Win32-Cases\ChangeDir\ChangeDir`? This what I need to find out...

What I want to say is `_chdrive` does what it is designed to do based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdrive?view=vs-2019): **Changes the current working drive**.

If you want to change directory use [`_chdir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir?view=vs-2019).

Comment: another way to test is to have the shortcut launch with a different current directory say, d:\testfolder, then the getcwd() returns d:\testfolder, then _chdrive over to C:, then back to D:, the getcwd() will be d:\, but if before you switch to c: you set the direct to d:\testfolder, when you go from C: back to D:, it will be correct.

Comment: @user3161924 Yes, set the directory make the system remember your expected directory.